# How to recover public key using ecRecover in Python?

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, web3.py, python, ecrecover

I am able to use ecRecover to verify the signer in Javascript, for example:

```
const ecRecoverAddr = await window.ethereum.request({
    method: "personal_ecRecover",
    params: [message, signedMessage],
});
```

However, when I try the following Python code:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

def verify(request, message, signedMessage):
    response = web3.geth.personal.ecRecover(message, signature)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='text/json')
```

I get this error:
`name 'web3' is not defined`

Does this mean that I need to instantiate some sort of provider for web3? What should be done?

Is there a way to retrieve the public key using ecRecover **without the use of a provider**?

Shouldn't it just be a method that can run without any connections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to instantiate the web3 object and cannot refer to a package here.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(<infura or alchemy URL>))

def verify(request, message, signedMessage):
    response = w3.geth.personal.ecRecover(message, signature)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='text/json')
```

Comment: For anyone else who may come across this post, use `w3.eth.account.recover_message` instead of the incorrect `w3.geth.personal.ecRecover`.

The signedMessage that I have comes from Web3.js, and is in the form `0xb47b9215304122fe5ae23aa6e89d9f01c8497fbeb903b8e8602e2db3d235c8af3f6b8fee791019045f44fe61dd9af193e3d241b108311893d1db852dc7d76d811c` however, when I try to pass that to `w3.eth.account.recover_message` in Python, I get the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'version'. What do I need to do?

Comment: @dx1 I recommend to create a new question for that issue.